# SQL & PHP query with union

Tags: php, sql, union

I have this query string...

```
select i.invoiceid, i.date, i.total, i.total - (select ifnull(sum(p.amount), 0) from payment p where p.invoice = i.invoiceid) as remainingbalance
        from invoice i inner join client c
        on i.client = c.clientid
        where i.isdeleted = 0 and i.client = 1
        union
        select p.paymentid, p.date, p.invoice, p.amount from payment p inner join invoice i
        on i.invoiceid = p.invoice
        inner join paymenttype
        on paymenttype.paymenttypeid = p.paymenttypeid
        inner join client c
        on c.clientid = i.client
        where c.clientid = 1
        and i.isdeleted = 0
        order by date
```

when I try this...

```
<?php
echo $clientArrayInvoice[1]['paymentid'];
?>
```

I get no results when I do a print_r on on $clientArrayInvoice I get this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [invoiceid] => 1 [date] => 2012-04-12 [total] => 602.29 [remainingbalance] => 300.96 ) [1] => Array ( [invoiceid] => 1 [date] => 2012-04-27 [total] => 1.00 [remainingbalance] => 301.33 ) )
```

I understand why its doing this, but how do I get the column to say `paymentid` instead of `invoiceid` for the results returned. so I can determine what is a `paymentid` and what is a `invoiceid` I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select i.invoiceid as transactionid, i.date, i.total, 
i.total - (select ifnull(sum(p.amount), 0) from payment p where p.invoice = i.invoiceid) as remainingbalance,
'invoice' as transaction_type
        from invoice i inner join client c
        on i.client = c.clientid
        where i.isdeleted = 0 and i.client = 1
        union
select p.paymentid as transactionid, p.date, p.invoice, p.amount, 'payment' as transaction_type
        from payment p inner join invoice i
        on i.invoiceid = p.invoice
        inner join paymenttype
        on paymenttype.paymenttypeid = p.paymenttypeid
        inner join client c
        on c.clientid = i.client
        where c.clientid = 1
        and i.isdeleted = 0
        order by date
```

Comment: thanks therealmitchconnors but this didnt work, when I tried to run it I got error around `on i.invoiceid = p.invoice
        inner join paymenttype`

Comment: the error occurs before that code actually at `from payment p inner join invoice i, 'payment' as transaction_type`

Comment: sorry, I had some formatting confusion... now it should work.